# Navigation Drawer Animation, drawerOpen is called twice

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to run an animation on navigation drawer open on one of my views, following is my code:

```
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                System.out.println("Called");

                ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(pw, "progress", 200); 
                animation.setDuration(1000);
                animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
                animation.start();
                //      mDrawerList.setLayoutAnimation(getMaximAnim());

                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

The console prints `Called` twice whenever I open the drawer, which means the animation will happen twice and it jitters this way. I want to animate the view only once, Where am I going wrong, any hints?

This is my drawerSlide code:

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if(slideOffset > .55 && !drawerOpen){
                onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                drawerOpen = true;
            } else if(slideOffset < .45 && drawerOpen) {
                onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                drawerOpen = false;
            }
        }
```

I have taken reference from [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Comment: Doesn't android call `onDrawerOpened()` automatically when the drawer is opened? Calling it in `onDrawerSlide()` will result in two calls in total, one from you via `onDrawerSlide()` and one from android directly via the event of `onDrawerOpened()`.

Comment: But then how do I set and change the titles / show and hide the views in the ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need

```
onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
```

in your onDrawerSlide. It's called by Android itself. As for changing titles, look at this:

```
public void restoreActionBar(){
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```

and set `mTitle` to any String you like in another part of code.

Comment: Then how do I aminate, as I use this function to animate my views?

Comment: try to use `your_drawer_variable.setOnDrawerOpenListener(new onDrawerOpenListener(){ public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){some code});`